# Append string to an Excel-cell, but ignore appended value when referenced in calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2019

I am wondering if there is a way to append a cell with a string value (for better/readable presentation), but ignore this appended value in formulas when referenced?

For example, lets say
A4 has the value =SUM(A1:A3)&" USD"
B4 has the value =SUM(B1:B3)&" USD"

Now, in A5 I want to have =(A4+B4)&" USD", and somehow have the A4+B4 formula ignore the appended " USD" in A4 and B4. Can I do this, or do I really have to keep a strict separation between calculations/formulas and presentation cells, and have "landing-cells" for calculations?

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom format that adds the text to the end, like:

```
0 U\S\D
```

[image]

As you can see the `USD` does not truly exist in the value and as such it is still a number and can be used in mathematical equations.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of this, thank you!
I have one more question though. What if I have a cell to decide, in this case the currency. Can I refer to this cell?

I.e., if I in A5 really have =(A4+B4)&" "&A6, where A6 can be set to "USD", "EUR" or whatever, can I make a reference to A6 instead of having a hardcoded value?

Comment: No, Custom format will not work with a reference.  At that point just use two cells.  One with the number and the other with the type. Hide the guidelines and add borders correctly so it appears as one cell.

Comment: @MahNas92 Conditional formatting *could* do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

With A1 similar to:

34.5 USD
created by e.g. `=B1&" "&C1`

you should be able to extract `34.5` with:

> `IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)),0)`

... in any formula.

*Assuming decimal-POINT in locale. Try 34,5 if not so.*